# How do I set user data directory in chromium-embedded with chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium-embedded

I am trying to use CEF for chrome profile like feature. After some Googling I found that CEF supports a similar capability via CefSettings.cache_path and --cache-path.

But I am unable to figure out how to set this capability via chromedriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass cache-path as an argument using chromeOptions.

Please find below sample code:

```
from selenium  import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chromeOptions = Options()

chromeOptions.add_argument("--cache-path=C:\\CEF\\c_path")
chromeOptions.binary_location = r"C:\cef_binary_client\Release\cefclient.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Driver\chromedriver_220.exe", chrome_options=chromeOptions)

driver.get("https://google.com")
s = "test" 
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(s)
```

Comment: Could you please provide me link to download cefclient.exe?